# How can I repair a torn out cabinet hinge mount?

Tags: repair, cabinets, particle-board

So the story goes that our roommate (who does not live with us anymore) slipped in the bathroom and somehow managed to break the cabinet door off the wall part of the cabinet. The point is when she pulled the door the bottom hinge tore out and caused a hole (approximately 3"x3.5") in the particle board wall of the cabinet. I don't know if there are any fillers I can use to patch this up that will hold the hinge and door. I'm fairly handy and have just recently started with simple wood working projects so please forgive my lack of terminology. I really do not want to replace this whole cabinet wall structure if I can avoid it. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to repair the finished outside surface as well, or does the damage not go all the way through the panel?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you include a picture or two of the damage?

Answer (score 2):

I have had success with 5 minute epoxy. The epoxy bonded well with the particle board and allowed for re-drilling of torn out screw holes.  If the hole is really big then you are looking at a "dutchman" patch.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to move the hinge above the damage and use a wood filler to fill the damaged area. Wood filler and or glue will not be strong enough to hold the hinge to the particle board for a permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

Bondo (auto body filler) may be your best bet here. Particle board is dreadful stuff, so is body filler, they work fine together in most cases, and it's a much more solid product than most wood fillers. Warning - it stinks. Use lots of ventilation.